# Does Spring interpret byte arrays as base64 encoded data

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I implemented a REST service using Java + Spring 3. One of these receives a byte array as part of the Json.

I found that if I consume it from another program and send my data as either a byte[] or a String in base64, they are both accepted and work correctly, I was wondering why is this, is it beacause bytes are interpreted by Spring as a String in base64 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does. I think it's the ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter that does that job for you, see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/converter/ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter.java